# Comparing Device Serial Numbers in Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, dictionary, iteration

Very very new at Python, and I have been trying to build a tool to help with device reconciliations at work.  We basically have four different systems of the same devices that need to be compared to complete the reconciliation reporting.

So far it works really well for cleaning the data from two of the systems and outputting two, new, CSVs with scrubbed data.

My next part of the project is where I am running into issues, and I have tried a lot of different things.  What I would like it to do, is take values from a specific key, compare them to a specific key in the other system dictionary, and then output a combo of data into a CSV for matching values.

So, if system_1 = {'serial': aaaaaa, 'type': ipad, 'imei': 12345} and system_2 = {'serial': aaaa, 'order number': 1}  -  When it iterates, it would match up the data based on serial number, and then output a CSV that would have 'sys1 serial', 'sys2 serial', 'sys2 order number', 'sys1 type', 'sys1 imei' for every serial number match.

Here is what I have done so far, with some attempts commented out:

```
import csv
import re

digits = r'[0-9]'

# Create the list of headers for the new file
jamf_headers = [
    'JAMF_LOCATION',
    'JAMF_SERIAL',
    'JAMF_IMEI',
    'JAMF_PHONE',
    'JAMF_MODEL',
    'JAMF_LAST_CHECKIN',
    'JAMF_LAST_INVENTORY'
]

abm_headers = [
    'ABM_SERIAL',
    'ABM_IMEI',
    'ABM_MODEL',
    'ABM_ORDER_NO',
    'ABM_DATE_REMOVED',
    'ABM_MDM'
]

combo_headers = [
    'JAMF_LOCATION',
    'JAMF_SERIAL',
    'ABM_SERIAL',
    'JAMF_IMEI',
    'ABM_IMEI',
    'JAMF_PHONE',
    'JAMF_MODEL',
    'ABM_ORDER_NO',
    'ABM_MDM',
    'ABM_DATE_REMOVED',
    'JAMF_LAST_CHECKIN',
    'JAMF_LAST_INVENTORY'
]

jamf_values = {}

# Open the files using the 'with' statement
with open('JAMF_Devices.csv', 'r') as jamf_data,\
     open('ABM_Devices.csv', 'r') as abm_data,\
     open('jamf_data_clean.csv', 'w', newline = '') as jamf_clean,\
     open('abm_data_clean.csv', 'w', newline = '') as abm_clean,\
     open('combined_data.csv', 'w', newline = '') as combo:

# Define our CSV readers and writers    
    jamf_reader = csv.reader(jamf_data)
    abm_reader = csv.reader(abm_data)
    jamf_writer = csv.DictWriter(jamf_clean, fieldnames = jamf_headers)
    abm_writer = csv.DictWriter(abm_clean, fieldnames = abm_headers)
    combined_writer = csv.DictWriter(combo, fieldnames = combo_headers)

# Skip header values
    next(jamf_reader)
    next(abm_reader)

    jamf_writer.writeheader()
    abm_writer.writeheader()
    combined_writer.writeheader()

# Loop through lines of the JAMF CSV reader and store to keys
    for line in jamf_reader:
        model = re.sub(digits, '', line[4])
        jamf_values = [{
        'JAMF_LOCATION': line[2].lower().strip(),
        'JAMF_SERIAL': line[0].strip(),
        'JAMF_IMEI': line[36].replace(' ', '').strip(),
        'JAMF_PHONE': line[34].replace('1', '', 1).strip(),
        'JAMF_MODEL': model.replace(',', ''),
        'JAMF_LAST_CHECKIN': line[13].split('T')[0],
        'JAMF_LAST_INVENTORY': line[14].split('T')[0]
        }]
#       print(jamf_values)
#       jamf_writer.writerows(jamf_values)
#       print(jamf_values.get('JAMF_SERIAL'))


        for line in abm_reader:
            abm_values = [{
            'ABM_SERIAL': line[0].strip(),
            'ABM_IMEI': line[1].strip(),
            'ABM_MODEL': line[2].strip(),
            'ABM_ORDER_NO': line[8].strip().split('_')[2],
            'ABM_DATE_REMOVED': line[10].strip().split('T')[0],
            'ABM_MDM': line[11].strip()
            }]
#           print(abm_values)
#           abm_writer.writerows(abm_values)            
#           print(abm_values.get('ABM_SERIAL')) 
    
'''     
    for line in jamf_reader:
        if line[0] in abm_reader:
            model = re.sub(digits, '', serial[4])
            combo_values = [{
            'JAMF_LOCATION': serial[2].lower().strip(),
            'JAMF_SERIAL': serial[0].strip(),
            'ABM_SERIAL': line[0].strip(),
            'JAMF_IMEI': serial[36].replace(' ', '').strip(),
            'ABM_IMEI': line[1].strip(),
            'JAMF_PHONE': serial[34].replace('1', '', 1).strip(),
            'JAMF_MODEL': model.replace(',', ''),
            'ABM_ORDER_NO': line[8].strip().split('_')[2],
            'ABM_MDM': line[11].strip(),
            'ABM_DATE_REMOVED': line[10].strip().split('T')[0],
            'JAMF_LAST_CHECKIN': serial[13].split('T')[0],
            'JAMF_LAST_INVENTORY': serial[14].split('T')[0]
            }]
            print(combo_values)
'''

#print(jamf_values)
```

I've tried not nesting the second system (abm-reader loop), but then I can't access the jamf_reader values because of scope.

In both jamf and abm loops, I tried removing the '[]' from the [{'key': value}] definitions so I could use dictionary methods, but then it won't write to CSV.

In the last block, I have tried nesting, not nesting, dictionary methods, etc... I can't get it to iterate at all.  I did have it nested once, and it did return one line perfectly, with matching serial numbers and all the info. I was pretty stoked for that.  However, there is like 1,400 serial numbers to iterate over.

Comment: Have you tried [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)?  Assuming the data is small enough that it can all fit in memory, you should be able to do something like `data_a = {row['serial']: row for row in csv.DictReader(file_a)}` (and again for the other source), then get all serials via `set(data_a) | set(data_b)`, then iterate over all serials and pull the info from either dataset via `data_x.get(serial)`

Comment: I haven't tried that yet.  I'll have to try that next.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To make this example a bit easier to follow, I am using the following simpler example CSVs:

`a.csv`:

```
serial,imei,type
aaa,123,foo
bbb,456,bar
ccc,789,baz
```

`b.csv`:

```
serial,order_no
aaa,x_y_1
bbb,x_y_2
ddd,x_y_5
```

We can define a couple functions to organize the loading and processing of the data:

```py
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter
from typing import Dict, List  # Using these in case you are using Python<3.8

SystemDataMap = Dict[str, Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]]


def normalize_row(row):
    # This could have an additional parameter for system name, if necessary, to change behavior accordingly
    try:
        row['order_no'] = row['order_no'].strip().split('_')[2]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    # ... and so on...
    return row


def load_data(system_path_map: Dict[str, str]) -> SystemDataMap:
    system_data_map = {}
    for system, path in system_path_map.items():
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            # Making each of these be dicts makes it easier to look up the system-specific data for a given serial number later
            system_data_map[system] = {row['serial']: normalize_row(row) for row in DictReader(f)}
    return system_data_map


def combine_data(system_data_map: SystemDataMap) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    combined = []
    # Create the all_serials set, containing only 1 entry per unique value
    all_serials = {serial for data in system_data_map.values() for serial in data}
    for serial in all_serials:
        combined_row = {'serial': serial}
        for system, serial_data_map in system_data_map.items():
            try:
                data = serial_data_map[serial]
            except KeyError:  # This system doesn't have this serial number
                pass
            else:
                for key, val in data.items():
                    combined_row[f'{system}_{key}'] = val

        combined.append(combined_row)

    return combined
```

---

The `{row['serial']: normalize_row(row) for row in DictReader(f)}` part is equivalent to the following:

```
serial_data_map = {}
for row in DictReader(f):  # each row is a dict of {column header: row value}
    serial_data_map[row['serial']] = normalize_row(row)
```

Similarly, the `all_serials = {serial for data in system_data_map.values() for serial in data}` line is equivalent to:

```
all_serials = set()
for data in system_data_map.values():
    for serial in data:
        all_serials.add(serial)
```

All nested list/dict/set/etc comprehensions can be translated into a series of nested traditional for loops, in the same order as the `for X in Y` clauses occur in the comprehension.

---

Putting the pieces together:

```py
system_path_map = {'a': 'a.csv', 'b': 'b.csv'}
system_data_map = load_data(system_path_map)

all_fields = ['serial']
# This ensures we capture all possible field names
# next(iter(...)) is very similar to some_list[0], but it works for non-sequences
all_fields.extend(f'{system}_{key}' for system, data in system_data_map.items() for key in next(iter(data.values())))

combined = combine_data(system_data_map)

with open('combined_data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = DictWriter(f, all_fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(combined)
```

The resulting file's contents:

```
serial,a_serial,a_imei,a_type,b_serial,b_order_no
ddd,,,,ddd,5
aaa,aaa,123,foo,aaa,1
bbb,bbb,456,bar,bbb,2
ccc,ccc,789,baz,,
```

With this approach, you can handle more than 2 sources at once, and dynamically create the output column names without needing to define all of them manually in advance.

For the data normalization steps, you can handle that in either `combine_data` or `load_data`, where you can dispatch the normalization of a given row to a system-specific normalization function.

Comment: Oh man, I had a feeling the answer would be super complex in relation to my current skill level.  However, I appreciate it!  I'll attempt this method next chance I get!

Comment: I added some additional explanation for the dict/set comprehensions - I can add more detail if you need it.

Comment: This is amazing.  I really appreciate all the extra explanation.  I think I have a pretty good idea of how its working after I read it a few times.